# LIBSVM : Same Labels for all tests?

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I have 500 feature vectors and everyone is labelled in range 1-6 for 6 classes. I'm storing them in a mat file which looks like:

```
m=load('TrainingData')
m = 
         Labels: [1x500 double] % labels for each class in 1-6
           Data: [500x20 double] % Vectors
```

According to some post on forum, I passed vectors in sparse format

```
TrData=sparse(m.Data);
```

Then I have passed this data to train svm using LIBSVM :

```
svm_model=svmtrain(Labels,TrData,'-c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1');
```

The generated model look like:

```
svm_model = 
    Parameters: [5x1 double]
      nr_class: 6
       totalSV: 500
           rho: [18x1 double]
         Label: [6x1 double]
    sv_indices: [500x1 double]
         ProbA: [18x1 double]
         ProbB: [18x1 double]
           nSV: [6x1 double]
       sv_coef: [500x5 double]
           SVs: [500x20 double]
```

Now I'm calculating feature vectors for 128 test files with labels

```
Test = 
        TLabels: [1x127 double]
          TData: [127x20 double]
```

Where, labels of test data are unknown, simply used any random `double` values [(as per readme file)](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91082/SVM/README) . And then passing it to testing phase viz.

```
testin=sparse(Test.TData);
[lbl,accu,prob] = svmpredict(TLabels, testin, svm_model, '-b 1');
```

and the doubtful part is all 127 vectors have `prob` as :

```
prob =
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.0000        0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
    0.1427        0.1427    0.1428    0.1436    0.1429    0.1427
```

With all labels 3 except one having all 0's as 6. And

```
Accuracy = 0.787402% (1/127) (classification)
```

Why is it so...?

Comment: Normally this behaviour means that you have to tweak your parameters more. I would need to see the data to recommend you some values, but the thumb rule is to increase the C and adjust the gamma so one support vector won't cover another.

Comment: how to decide C value and gamma values? means is there any rule for that ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not universal rule for that. However, there are good approaches that can be very helpful. Libsvm comes with a tool called grid.py that performs a grid search using crossvalidation between a range of values. Here are a couple of links that might help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/gridsearch-for-svm-parameter-estimation      http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/how-does-one-appropriately-apply-cross-validation-in-the-context-of-selecting-le