# LIBSVM:Unknown predict Labels gives accurecy 0%

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, libsvm

According to [readme](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r94100/libsvm-2.8/README) file, `If labels are unknown, just fill this column with a number.` So I put random numbers as prediction labels but the accuracy is 0% for 120 test files. My svm_model is trained with 520 training feature vectors. Is the prediction based on labels ? I doubt because when I used 1-5 (i.e. my class labels) as test labels, the accuracy is around 60%. And if so then what does `If labels are unknown, just fill this column with a number.` mean ?

Comment: If you find confusing the differences among training, validation and test sets, have a look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Answer (score 0):

When you are predicting, the labels are just for reference to calculate the accuracy. If the labels are unknown then you have to ignore the accuracy since the library doesn't have any value to compare to and identify if the prediction is correct or not.

Comment: actually, though I'm getting accuracy of 60% for those 120 test vectors(in case I'm passing 1-5 labels as input), the prob vector for each of them is same. LIBSVM is too confusing...

Comment: @kamol It is not that confusing once you get used to it :) I would recommend you that if you are starting to learn it, don't pay too much attention to the prob numbers, they can be deceptive under some conditions. If you know the labels in your test set, then the accuracy number will save you the hassle of calculating manually, but that just it.

Comment: I've used LIBSVM with another test and train data. My [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637545/libsvm-same-labels-for-all-tests) highlights the problem of prob distribution. I would like to have your opinion on that.

Comment: i have also similar problem,how can you predict unknown label of your test set if you training set has known labels?

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan You don't have the labels in your training set? If you have an unlabelled training set that's pretty much the definition of unsupervised learning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning). Maybe I could help if you provide more details.

Comment: ah,thanks @Pedrom,i actually misunderstood the exercice i was doing,i was using liblinear and i had to predict label from test set given the the training set labels and evaluate with labels from the exercise organizer(which i dont have),thanks alot for your help